# Payload gets lost during CORS PUT request

Tags: ajax, apache

I have a webpacked client application running on localhost:8080 and an Silex PHP application running with apache on localhost:80

I try to send a PUT request with axios on the client to the silex application with a request payload. But somehow in the silex application I see no payload, the request parameters bag is empty.

This is my vHost CORS config:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:8080"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, x-requested-by, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

And these are the request and response headers.
[image]

I really don't know what is missing here, I never had any problems with this.

Comment: This doesn’t seem like something that your CORS config would affect. Have you tried testing by sending the same request with `curl`? For example: `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"deleteChanges" : [], …}' http://example.com`.

Comment: I guess you mean `-X` for the PUT request? It returns me an HTML with an bad request error.

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't had the right command entered. It returns the same result, no payload. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. Turns out that Silex just does not support JSON formatted content on a request.